# Postgresql-Insert value come up with non-null conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, error-handling

```
insert into "StarSchema"."Customer" 
(address,address2,district,postal_code,phone)
select address,address2,district,postal_code,phone
from public.address;
```

I'm trying to insert value from another table into the table I created just now. But I don't know why there are conflict of non-null. As this query didn't contain (customer_id) which is the primary key. And I didn't have any value defined in schema require non-null. There are some values in address2 and postal_code are null. When I remove these two columns in queries. Everything works fine. Is there any method to bring all columns into the new table?

```
    CREATE TABLE "StarSchema"."Customer"
(
    first_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    last_name character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    activebool boolean,
    create_date date,
    address character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    address2 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    district character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    postal_code character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    city character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    country character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    phone character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    customer_id integer NOT NULL,
    email character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    active integer,
    CONSTRAINT "Customer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
)
```

The error information in the question is
Error: Null value violates non-null constraint in field "customer_id"

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you want `customer_id` to be assigned automatically.  If so, define it as:

```
customer_id integer generated always as identity primary key,
```

Or in older versions of Postgres:

```
customer_id serial primary key,
```

As a side note, I usually make the primary key the *first* column in the table, not the last.

Answer (score 0):

Primary keys are implicitly `NOT NULL`, so you cannot enter a NULL value for `customer_id`. Omitting a column in an `INSERT` statement means to insert the default value, which is NULL in your case.

Comment: I'm actually giving values to other columns. The value  for customer_id contain no nulls. This is the second query after I  insert values to customer_id. I don't know why

Comment: An `INSERT` always gives values to all columns. Could it be that you are mixing up `INSERT` and `UPDATE`?